# executing an exe using sandboxie with parameters

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, echo

I have an exe written in cpp, which I would like to execute in a sandbox called Sandboxie.
The exe file is requesting for input (using cin command in cpp), the only way I found passing parameters not within argv but for cin is with echo command.
the output of the exe file will go to txt file.
basically, if my program asks for one input, the run command looks like this :

```
start "D:\Program Files\Sandboxie\start.exe" /B (echo 3) | exetorun.exe > result.txt
```

The problem I found here is that it just doesn`t work,
so the solution I found is taking the part of parameters pass and exe name to run and inserting it into a batch file (.bat) and running it from the sandbox.
like that :

```
start "D:\Program Files\Sandboxie\start.exe" /B "runExec.bat"
```

and runExec.bat will have :

```
( echo 3 ) | exetorun.exe > output.txt
```

The problem now is that I have the basic version of Sandboxie which does not let you define a folder for example that no matter what when you try to run a file from there - it will run it from the sandbox... so basically all my points of sandbox is ruined. 
Moreover, the idea of making a batch file for that is pretty stupid I think...

The only solution I find that will be the pretties is finding a way to just run the command of executing the wanted file and passing the wanted paramter to it within the first command instead of creating a batch file that will execute those commands.

Does someone know a way in any aspect (another sandbox, how to run the command not from a batch file) that can solve this ?

Thanks !

Comment: `start "" "D:\Program Files\Sandboxie\start.exe" /B  cmd /c "echo 3 | exetorun.exe > result.txt"`

Comment: I see, I tried to run this line and I get an error from sandboxie: "Invalid command line parameter: B cmd /c (echo 3)

Comment: @sitoNz This appears because you are passing parameter to Sandboxie's start.exe. This parameter is from the `start` command. Try putting the parameter before: `start /B "D:\Program Files\Sandboxie\start.exe" cmd /c "echo 3 | exetorun.exe > result.txt"`